# how to remove the last comma between 2 prime number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0 , b=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i = a+1;i < b;i++){
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 2;j <= i / 2;j++){
            if(i % j == 0){
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 0 && i!= 1){
            cout<<i<<",";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to remove the last comma from this code? I think we have to add 1 if statement but I don't know what should I do... please help me thanks

Comment: You can't really remove stuff from a stream. Once it's written, consider it gone. It could already be on the screen, in a file, out a socket, whatever. You can try to chase it with a backspace, but that has iffy results. The best course of action is to not write it in the first place.

Comment: `int num_primes = 0`.....`if (num_primes++) {cout << ","; } cout << i;` This prints the comma before the number - except the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of always printing the number followed by a comma, you can change your logic to the following:

If it is the first time you are printing a number, only print the number. Otherwise, print a comma before printing the number.

That way, the last number will never have a comma printed behind it.

I suggest that you add the following declaration before both loops:

```
bool first = true;
```

Now you can change

```
if(counter == 0 && i!= 1){
    cout<<i<<",";
}
```

to:

```
if ( counter == 0 && i != 1 ) {
    if ( first )
        first = false;
    else
        cout << ',';
    cout << i;
}
```

Comment: it fixed, really thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do so. Just display 2 separately and then comma and the number afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=0 , b=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<2;
    for(int i = a+1;i < b;i++){
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j = 2;j <= i / 2;j++){
            if(i % j == 0){
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 0 && i > 2){
            cout<<","<<i<<;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```